# Loggin Session issue with field prepolated already

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a little issue, I try to create a loggin session and in work  almost well the issue is in when I run the loggin view the fields have information already and I want that these field are in blank.

```
<h1 class="cuadro_titulo container letramenu">Log in</h1>

<section class = "fondo_form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 cuadro_info">
      <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
        <div>
           <%= f.label :usuario, class: "Etiqueta_campo"  %>
           <p>
             <%= f.text_field :usuario, :value => nil, placeholder: "Escribe 
                aqui usuario", class: "campo_peq" %>
           </p>
        </div>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, :value => "", autocompleate: "off" 
         %>

        <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary campo_peq centrar" %>
      <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcU9o.jpg)

I will apriciate any idea,  thanks

Comment: Its your browser issue. You can remove the saved credentials here https://www.bu.edu/tech/services/cccs/desktop/software/troubleshooting/removing-password-from-browsers-saved-password-list/.

Comment: Thank you very much,  It works well.